# Difference between organisation member and outside collaborator in github

Tags: github

The [github docs](https://help.github.com/categories/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/) are a bit unclear about the semantic difference between organisation member and outside collaborator. What is the distinction?

I run an github organisation for my school. I create repos and allocate them to students. Should the students be members of the org or outside collaborators?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This particular [GitHub Help Doc page](https://help.github.com/articles/converting-an-organization-member-to-an-outside-collaborator/) may help clear it up.  Outside collaborators only have access to repositories that their team membership allows.  Outside collaborators cannot create teams or view all the organization's members and teams.

> [Outside collaborators and bot accounts will count toward your organization's total of paid seats if they are given access to a private repository.](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-billing-and-payments-on-github/about-per-user-pricing)

Comment: But they still take up a seat, the same as a regular team member, right?

Comment: From my testing, members not on a team cannot see a roster of organization members and cannot see hidden teams either, though. So is repo access the only difference?

Comment: Outside collaborators are also in someway hidden from other users. Their profile picture and link don't show and they are not accounted for at the insights.

Comment: @unclesol, "Outside collaborators and bot accounts will count toward your organization's total of paid seats if they are given access to a private repository." -- https://help.github.com/articles/about-per-user-pricing/

Comment: The usage of outside collaborator is still a bit unclear, has anyone a real-world usage for this? Would probably help :)

Comment: Outside collaborators can't be on a team only members. Annoying, but true. https://github.community/t5/How-to-use-Git-and-GitHub/Add-outside-collaborators-to-a-team-without-giving-them-acess-to/td-p/30135

Comment: Real world usage example: I’m currently setting up a GitHub organization for the EnOcean Alliance. Under the umbrella of the alliance, multiple technical working groups (TWG) work on standardizing specific aspects of the EnOcean technology. Those groups are made up of members of different companies. Members of a TWG could be added as outside collaborators to repositories related to the TWG’s scope. The inability to add outside collaborators to groups might make us reconsider that approach though.

Comment: Bit old topic but now outside collaborators can be part of Teams

Comment: @toto', could you clarify or share any doc on how to add outside collaborators to a Team? I could not do that, nor find any doc about it.

Comment: @Klim wouldn't this help you https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/managing-repository-settings/managing-teams-and-people-with-access-to-your-repository#inviting-a-team-or-person ? Once you have collaborators added to your organization you should be able to add them to Teams as you would with members.

Comment: @toto', thanks for the link. I don't think the flow you described is working. You can add an outside collaborator to the repo, but you cannot add them to the teams. Only Members can be part of the Team to my experiments and according to the docs.

Comment: @toto' be careful when you add them to a team, github will convert them to members

Answer (score 4):

Many people are confused by the real-world usage of outside collaborators.

Here is the real-world use case:

Your company launched 2 projects, called Project A (PA) and Project B (PB). They are maintained by 2 different "outside collaborators/teams" named Team A (TA) and Team B (TB).

TA manages PA, and TB manages PB.

Organization members can see any projects created within the organization. There is no way to change this, at least for now.

Outside collaborator is used to restrict the visibility of packages within an organization. For instance, invite team TA to project PA, team TB to project PB, and NOT add any of team TA or team TB as an organization member.

Answer (score 0):

Since outside collaborators are not members of an organization, they do not fall within the realm of base permissions that define default access to repos. Base member permissions are described [here](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-organization-settings/managing-base-permissions-for-projects) and general access considerations including for collaborators [here](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/planning-and-tracking-with-projects/managing-your-project/managing-access-to-your-projects).

What this means in practice is that all organization members have Read access at a minimum to every repo (conforming to the base permission setting) but outside collaborators must be invited explicitly to each repo.  Permissions within a repo can be managed as needed for both members and collaborators, but it's the default access that distinguishes the two user types.